# TypeError converting circular structure to json at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, json

```
var chartjson = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [{
      data: [],
      lineTension: 0,
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      borderColor: '#007bff',
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointBackgroundColor: '#007bff'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: false
        }
      }]
    },
    legend: {
      display: false,
    }
  }
};

var step = 1;

if (data.num < 10)
  step = parseInt(data.num / 10);

for (var i = 1; i < data.num + 1; i = i + step) {
  chartjson.data.labels.push(i);
  chartjson.data.datasets[0].data.push(data.dataList[i - 1].temperature);
}

setChart(chartjson);
sessionStorage.chartjson = JSON.stringify(chartjson);
```

There is not hava circular. The JSON chartjson is directly defined, and don't reference any variables. I can't find any circular structure. The 'data' is a JSON object like that:

```
{
  "num": 100,
  "dataList": [
    {
      "temperature": 33.1,
      "g1": 1.21,
      "g2": 0.11,
      "g3": 7.7,
      "time": "2018-08-03 08:30:33"
    },
    {
      "temperature": 33.2,
      "g1": 1.11,
      "g2": 0.21,
      "g3": 7.7,
      "time": "2018-08-03 08:31:19"
    },
    {
      "temperature": 33.3,
      "g1": 1.4,
      "g2": 0.01,
      "g3": 7.6,
      "time": "2018-08-03 08:31:42"
    },
    {
      "temperature": 33.4,
      "g1": 1.41,
      "g2": 0.01,
      "g3": 7.7,
      "time": "2018-08-03 08:32:06"
    }
  ]
}
```

I get the Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: What does `setChart` do? Most likely some other function is adding a property to the object.

Comment: How does the object look like right before the stringify?

Comment: Please share a working stackblitz, where i can debug the issue. Thanks!!

Comment: Ohhh, yeah, setChart function reference the chartjson and change it, and make it become a circular structure. I just change "setChart(chartjson)" and "sessionStorage.chartjson = JSON.stringify(chartjson);" 's order. And it become right. Thank you.

Comment: What line causes the error?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice sessionStorage.chartjson = JSON.stringify(chartjson);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohhh, yeah, setChart function reference the chartjson and change it, and make it become a circular structure. I just change "setChart(chartjson)" and "sessionStorage.chartjson = JSON.stringify(chartjson);" 's order. And it become right. Thank you.